# I am trying to install IPFS module with NPM but getting following error

Tags: node.js, npm-install, ipfs

I am trying to install the IPFS module from NPM but getting the following error.
Any solutions to this problem?
[error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kV6X.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a IPFS issue, rather just an annoyance from using npm on Linux. Check their docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions